# How to parse rss feeds using volley?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-volley, rss-reader

I am making an app in which I have to parse RSS feeds from 5-6 different urls and show them in different activities. I have tried using Async Tas, but it runs only in main activity. So, is there any way to parse these XML data using volley and show them in different activities?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem of RSS is that there's no standard format. There're RSS 0.90, RSS 0.91, RSS 0.92, RSS 1.0, RSS 1.1, RSS 2. Unfortunately for each version the response XML is different.

First of all, I can't give your answer using Volley.

Good news is on Github, there's a library which can convert RSS feed of any version from URL. You can check from [Here](https://github.com/ernieyu/simple-feed-parser)

Comment: Is there any tutorial available on how to use it?

Comment: sorry, can't find my example. I used this library for RSS feeding (any version of RSS). I used async task ... look at their git repo. hopefully You'll be benefited. thanks :)